# A graph with diameter $2$

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that we have a graph $G$ having $n$ vertex with diameter $2$ ,

Let $M=max\{deg(v_i) \}$ where $v_i$ are vertex of $G$ then $M\geq n-3$.

I just made up this. It can be wrong but I could not find counter example.

Any counter example or proof is welcome.

Comment: How did you come to this result ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom: Kind of intuation, it can be wrong.

Comment: `n-3`, intuitive? Hmmm...

Comment: @Did: Don't you believe me ? :)

Comment: Depends on your definition of intuition. With mine, this does not fit.

Comment: @Did: $n-1$ max possible degree ,$2$ diameter is it $n-1-2$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counter example :
Let $\Sigma=\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_k\}$ a finite set.
Define a graph $G$ such that

- The set of vertices is $\Sigma^2$
- Two vertices $xy$ and $zt$ are neighbours if and only if $x=z$ or $y=t$.
- Hence diameter of $G$ is 2, number of vertices is $k^2$ and $M=2k-2$

As soon as $2k-2\le k^2-3$ it is a counter example.

Comment: Very nice example thank you. I compute $M$ as $2k-1$, Am I missing something ?

Comment: Ok I see now. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can prove from this example that $M\approx\sqrt[D]{n}$.